# Not getting any albums from my database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a task for work by following a certain tutorial concerning image uploading website. The part where I got stuck is showing created albums. This is relevant code (ask for more if I missed anything).

```
function get_albums() {

$albums = array();

$albums_query = mysql_query("
SELECT `albums`.`album_id`, `albums`.`timestamp`, `albums`.`name`,     LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `images`
ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = ".$_SESSION["user_id"]."
GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`
");


while($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query))
{
    $albums[] = array(
                      'id' => $albums_row["album_id"],
                      'timestamp' => $albums_row["timestamp"],
                      'name' => $albums_row["name"],
                      'description' => $albums_row["description"],
                      'count' => $albums_row["image_count"]
                      );
}

return $albums;


}
function create_album($album_name, $album_description) {
    $album_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_name));
    $album_description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_description));

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `albums` VALUES ('', '".$SESSION["user_id"]."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$album_name', '$album_description')");
        mkdir('uploads/' .mysql_insert_id(), 0744);
        mkdir('uploads/thumbs/' .mysql_insert_id(), 0744);


}
```

That's all that I recognize as relevant and where I think problem is located.This is where albums should show:

```
<?php
$albums = get_albums();

if (empty($albums)) {
 echo '<p> You don\'t have any albums</p>';
} else {

    foreach ($albums as $album) {
        echo '<p>
        <a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'], '">', $album['name'], '</a> (', $album['count'], ' images)<br />
        ', $album['description'], '...<br />

        <a href="edit_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'], '">Edit</a> / <a href="delete_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'], '">Delete</a>
        </p>';
    }
}

include 'template/footer.php'
```

?>

But I am always getting a message that I don't have albums, which leads me to think he always sees albums array as empty. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Besides the mysql adapter's deprecation, I don't see any issue with the code itself either, so I'd suggest testing the code using a known user ID instead of the session variable, if rows are found that way, then the session is to blame. If that pulls up nothing, then test the SQL directly (phpmyadmin or mysql workbench) to see if the SQL statement is to blame, if rows are found that way, then the php is to blame and we will have another look, otherwise the SQL statement is to blame.

Comment: Tested both SQL and session variable, the problem isn't there.

Comment: So if you do a var_dump inside of the function on mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query), you do get results?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_SESSION["user_id"]`, but I did not see a `session_start()` anywhere in your file. It could be that your session is not populated.

The other possibility is that your user doesn't have any albums.

As an aside, please migrate your scripts to `mysqli`:

> It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It
>   is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development,
>   as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the
>   future.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Session start is in include above, and albums are created and shown in the base and as directories in file structure, it's just array is refusing to retrieve table data. Sorry if I sound like I dont know what I'm talking about, trying my best here to make sense.